# Modelica - Model variants (Standard one and more complex one)

Tags: inheritance, modelica

Even if using Modelica since several months, I am new to advanced features such as inheritance and replacements.

I have a standard model (i.e. of a pool) and a more complex variant (i.e. including evaporation calculations): the two model have many common parts that I want to "reuse" but they also have some differences: some equations (i.e mass and energy balance equations) are different (the complex model has more terms) and the complex model includes more parameters, variables and equations (i.e. air and vapor properties and laws).

I think I have some possibilities in Modelica to do that:

1. Write down two independent model (only using the wonderful not syncing copy-paste text feature) -- I prefer not to.
2. Use inheritance (1) to write a partial model with common definitions and two inheriting models with specific parts.
3. Use inheritance (2) to write two partial models containing the different sets of equations (and the other specific definitions) and write a third model containing the common definitions and inheriting one of the two partial model (choosing for example via a Boolean parameter). Actually I am not really sure I can do that: partial models would contain equations with undefined variables/parameters (which would be defined in the inheriting model): is that OK?
4. Write the standard model and replace the equations with new ones, also adding the additional definitions.

I achieved in (2), see example 1 below. However I do not understand how to use the replacement mechanism (see my failing attempt in example 2). Where am I wrong?

The examples below are simplified models I wrote trying to understand how to do it.

Example 1

```
package Inherited_base

  partial model Base
    parameter Real a=1;
    parameter Real b=2;
    Real c;
    Real d;
  equation 
    c+d = b;
  end Base;

  model Variant_1
    extends Base;
  equation 
    c = time*a;
  end Variant_1;

  model Variant_2
    extends Base;
    parameter Real e=0.5;
    Real d;
  equation 
    c+d*e = time*a;
  end Variant_2;

end Inherited_base;
```

Example 2

```
  model Base
    parameter Real a=1;
    parameter Real b=2;

    class Eqs
    Real c;
    Real d;
    equation 
        c = time*a;
    end Eqs;


  equation 

    replaceble Eqs bouclage;
    bouclage.c+bouclage.d = b;

  end Base;
```

---

Edit: I tried to answer to my question in bullet 3: I got error messages while defining a partial model where variables/parameters used in the equations are not defined within the class. I solved the issue by slightly modifying my idea: I use the same equation for both cases but I had a term ('extra' in the example) who take into account different variables/parameters to be used depending on the case. However, it looks like it is impossible to interactively chose the model from which to expand: the example here after is erroneous (without the "if" and with only one 'extends' it is fine).

Example 3

```
package Inherited_variants

  model Final
    parameter Real a=1;
    parameter Real b=2;
    Real c;
    Real d;
    parameter Boolean complexmodel = false;
    if complexmodel then
      extends Variant_2;
    else
      extends Variant_1;
    end if;
  equation 
    c+d = b;
    c+extra = time*a;
  end Final;

  partial model Variant_1
    parameter Real extra=0;
  end Variant_1;

  partial model Variant_2
    parameter Real e=0.5;
    Real d;
    Real extra;
  equation 
    extra = d*e;
  end Variant_2;

end Inherited_variants;
```

---

Edit after Scott G and Hans Olsson answers (thanks to both of you!).
The examples were interesting but I was still confused by the wide use of "extends" in your examples. So I tried to simplify your codes and also learned something from [here](http://book.xogeny.com/components/architectures/replaceable/).

Scott's example rearranged:

```
package Example

  partial model FinalTerm
  end FinalTerm;

  model Final

    model Variant_1
       extends FinalTerm;
       parameter Real extra=0;
    end Variant_1;

    parameter Real a=1;
    parameter Real b=2;
    Real c;
    Real d;

    replaceable model VarType = Variant_1 constrainedby FinalTerm annotation(choicesAllMatching=true);

    //replaceable model VarType = Variant_1 constrainedby FinalTerm annotation(choices(choice=redeclare Variant_2 VarType,
    //                                                                                  choice=redeclare Variant_1 VarType));

    VarType varType;

  equation 

     c+d = b;
     c+varType.extra*d = time*a;

  end Final;

  model Variant_2
      extends FinalTerm;
      parameter Real e=0.5;
      Real extra;
  equation 
      extra = e;
  end Variant_2;

end Example;
```

Hans' example rearranged:

```
package Example_2

  partial model FinalTerm
  end FinalTerm;

  model Final

    model Variant_1
       extends FinalTerm;
       parameter Real extra=0;
    end Variant_1;

    parameter Real a=1;
    parameter Real b=2;
    Real c;
    Real d;

    replaceable Variant_1 test constrainedby FinalTerm annotation(choicesAllMatching=true);
    //replaceable Variant_1 test constrainedby FinalTerm annotation(choices(choice=redeclare Variant_2 test "NEW",
    //                                                                      choice=redeclare Variant_1 test "OLD"));

  equation 

     c+d = b;
     c+test.extra*d = time*a;

  end Final;

  model Variant_2
      extends FinalTerm;
      parameter Real e=0.5;
      Real extra;
  equation 
      extra = e;
  end Variant_2;

end Example_2;
```

What I understood (or at least I think):

- The difference between the two examples/approaches. For the use I intended I personally prefer the Hans' approach (component replacement). However, to perform several components replacement at once, Scott's one is more appropriated.
- The use of the 'extends' is not mandatory. The only use I found is to allow the use of 'constrainedby' which has to refer to a ~common-mother-class~ (sorry for my improper wording); this, combined to the 'annotation' provided by Scott, allows to have a dropdown menu in the parameters which is not useless (and that can also be used with the Hans' technique).

One little question remains open: according to [the previous webpage](http://book.xogeny.com/components/architectures/replaceable/) it should be possible to define the 'annotation(choices())' list by hand but I did not succeed (see commented lines in the previous examples). This would allow a proper dropdown menu without the need of using the "common-mother-class" to 'extend' and the 'constrainedby' keyword. Does somebody know where am I wrong?

Comment: I believe I have addressed your new question in my updated answer. Using parenthesis `choices(choice())` rather than `choices(choice= stuff)` seem to solve the issue. Note. I believe this is a nuance of `redeclare` that perhaps was changed since Tiller updated that portion of Modelica By Example as `choice=stuff` still is appropriate for other cases. Not sure though.

Comment: Thanks for this additional answer. The `choices(choice= stuff)` solution works properly, at least for the 'component replacement'. For 'type' replacement, the proper drop-down menu appears but the choice is not stored by the tool (Dymola) and finally the standard option is always taken.

Comment: I better looked into your example and I see that you applies this solution only to 'component' replacement, not to type. So I just used the wrong syntax. The valid one is: 
`annotation(choices(
 choice(redeclare model VarType = Test_ModelicaComplexity.Replacement_SO.Example_1.Variant_2 "NEW"),
 choice(redeclare model VarType = Variant_1 "STD")));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `replaceable model` to change between models rather than the `if` statements. Below is an example loosely based on you examples. I'll leave it to you to rethink about how to properly formulate your problem to use the replaceable feature correctly. Hope it helps.

Tested in Dymola 2017 FD01...

Not sure if OMEdit will handle `replaceable` use correctly as there seems to have been some long term issues that are still being addressed:
https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/2079.

```
package Example

  model Test
  // Simple test of the component "Final"

    Final Final1(
      redeclare model VarType = Variant_1,
      redeclare Variant_2 varType2,
      redeclare Example.Variant_3 varType3 "Test")
      annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}})));
  end Test;

  model Final
  // Model demonstrating difference ways to use "replaceable"

    extends ReplaceableModels.PartialModel;

    replaceable model VarType = ReplaceableModels.Variant_1 constrainedby 
      ReplaceableModels.PartialVariants
                              annotation(choicesAllMatching=true);

    VarType varType1;

    replaceable ReplaceableModels.Variant_1 varType2 constrainedby 
      ReplaceableModels.PartialVariants annotation (choicesAllMatching=true);

    replaceable ReplaceableModels.Variant_1 varType3 constrainedby 
      ReplaceableModels.PartialVariants annotation (choices(
        choice(redeclare Example.Variant_1 varType3 "OLD"),
        choice(redeclare Example.Variant_2 varType3 "NEW"),
        choice(redeclare Example.Variant_3 varType3 "Test")));

  equation 
       result1 = varType1.extra;
       result2 = varType2.extra;
       result3 = varType3.extra;

  end Final;

  model Variant_1

      extends ReplaceableModels.PartialVariants;

      parameter Real extra0=0;

  equation 
    extra = extra0;

  end Variant_1;

  model Variant_2

      extends ReplaceableModels.PartialVariants;

      parameter Real a=1;
      Real b;
      Real c;
      parameter Real e=0.5;
      parameter Real d = 0.1;

  equation 

      c+d = b;
      c+extra = time*a;
      extra = d*e;

  end Variant_2;

  model Variant_3

      Real extra;

      parameter Real a=1;
      Real b;
      Real c;
      parameter Real e=0.5;
      parameter Real d = 0.1;

  equation 

      c+d = b;
      c+extra = time*a;
      extra = d*e;

  end Variant_3;

  partial model PartialModel

    Real result1;
    Real result2;
    Real result3;

  end PartialModel;

  partial model PartialVariants

    Real extra;

  end PartialVariants;
end Example;
```

UPDATE:

Added annotation so that from the gui you have a drop down arrow for model selection.

UPDATE 2:

I have replaced the original code with an expanded example that demonstrates a few different methods using replaceable based on the poster's additional question. The code also now includes a `Test` of the model created (`Final`) and includes Variant_3 which does not extend from a partial class to show how the `choices` annotation allows you to also include extra models if that is useful for your case.

Answer (score 3):

I still can recommend section five of https://modelica.org/events/Conference2003/Modelica03-AdvancedTutorial.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Scott G's solution is to use a replaceable component instead (using his code as a basis):

```
package ReplaceableComponentTest
  model Test2 "Showing how to change it"
    extends Final(redeclare Example.Variant_2 varType);
  end Test2;

  model Final
    extends Example.PartialModel;
    replaceable Example.Variant_1 varType constrainedby 
      Example.PartialVariants annotation(choices(
             choice(redeclare Example.Variant_2 test "NEW"),
             choice(redeclare Example.Variant_1 test "OLD")));
  equation 
       result = varType.extra;
  end Final;
end ReplaceableComponentTest;

package Example

  model Variant_1
      extends Example.PartialVariants;
      parameter Real extra0=0;
  equation 
    extra = extra0;
  end Variant_1;

  model Variant_2
      extends Example.PartialVariants;

      parameter Real a=1;
      Real b;
      Real c;
      parameter Real e=0.5;
      parameter Real d = 0.1;

  equation 
      c+d = b;
      c+extra = time*a;
      extra = d*e;
  end Variant_2;

  partial model PartialModel

    Real result;

  end PartialModel;

  partial model PartialVariants

    Real extra;

  end PartialVariants;
end Example;
```

Both work for this case. Note that I added choices-annotation as well - and just to be safe used the full name of the classes (even if it should work).

Using a replaceable model is needed if you have multiple components of that model, and in other cases it is more a matter of style.